# Different Override method based on condition

Tags: java, android

This is an Android project but the question is more related to JAVA itself.

I'm trying to override a method in an `Activity` but I want this method to run different code based on two conditions: if a user is logged in and what type of user.

The method I'm overriding is the `dispatchTouchEvent` which is called, at least one time, every time the user touches the screen.

I could put the conditions inside the method however as a mention earlier, this is a method that is called a lot so I was trying to avoid doing extra logic over and over on it.

Ideally I wanted something like this:

```
if (isUserLogged) {
    if (user.getType == 'A') {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (//condition based on ev)
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            if (//different condition based on ev)
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is not possible.

Any tips on how I could avoid putting all the code inside the method?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to avoid an if statement in the method.

Comment: The thing you are trying to do is not possible, rather then overriding try to call different methods as per your need here

Comment: You can have multiple implementations of the Activity (ActivityLoggedIn vs ActivityNotLoggedIn) and use the one you want but I wouldn't care in practice and put the `if` inside. Modern processors don't care about ifs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create different implementations of an interface which shares the `dispatchTouchEvent` method. Take a look at the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: It is probably the right answer but it evolves a bit too much work. Zapl pointed out that ifs don't take much time in the processor so I'll go with putting all the logic inside and if I see that get's getting more complex than previously planned I'll have to switch to this option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure you know this is not possible, something similar is possible and quite possibility what you want. Maybe just using an if/switch inside your `onCall()` method and then call an appropriate method.

**Example**

```
public void onTouch(SomeEvent e){
    if(a){
        methodA();
    } else if (b) {
        methodB();
    }
}

void methodA ();//for simplicity
void methodB ();
```